# Javascript fetch request is not registered

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, async-await

I'm sending a fetch request to my server after authentication using firebaseui. However the fetch request is never registered on the server with console log. The page is redirect to redirectURI assigned without actually saving the data on server

This is the code responsible for sending post request

```
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
        signInOptions: [
                firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        callbacks: {
            signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async function (authResult, redirectUrl) {
                const response = await fetch("https://localhost:8000/test", {
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    cache: 'no-cache',
                    credentials: 'same-origin', 
                    headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    },
                    redirect: 'follow',
                    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
                    body: JSON.stringify(authResult)
                });
                return true;
            },
            uiShown: function () {
                document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
            }
        },
        signInFlow: 'redirect',
        signInSuccessUrl: '/auth/success',

        // Terms of service url.
        tosUrl: '/terms-of-service',
        // Privacy policy url.
        privacyPolicyUrl: '/privacy-policy'

    });
```

This is how it's handled on server for this post request

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log("A request recieved on test server");
    res.send("It works");
})
```

Comment: What does "Network" tab in browser devtools show?

Comment: @ezhikov It doesn't show up in Network tab too.

Comment: This means that you don't call your function

Comment: A call to the function is being made. I've verified it with console log and cookies.